# loop a string array in php foreach

Tags: php, foreach, drupal

I have a problem in foreach in php. i have dynamic data coming from database in the front end. but some paragraph is manual but it should change with the foreach loop.

```
$para = array
(
array("one","Get an authentic taste of the Malabar Coast as you cruise through the green Nilgiris and feast on the ancient history of the South.","Take a tour through the idyllic beaches of the Konkan Coast, while absorbing the rich culture of the majestic forts and stunning Sahyadri Hills.")
);
$i = 1;
foreach($allRides as $rides){ 
if ($i == 3) {
$i = 1;
}
$detail = $rides->_field_data['nid']['entity'];
$title = $detail->title;
$noofdays = $detail->field_tour_days['und'][0]['value'];
$noofdetails = $detail->field_more_details_of_the_tour['und'][0]['value'];
$noofdetailshort = $para[0][$i];
$image = image_style_url("homepage_ride",$detail->field_large_image['und'][0]['uri']);
$articleURL = url("node/".$rides->nid,array("absolute"=>true));
?>
<div class="places-slider-list">
<a href="<?php echo $articleURL;?>">
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $title;?>">
</a>
<article class="places-slider-data">
<h4><?php echo $title;?></h4>
<p><?php echo $noofdays;?> Day Guided Tour</p>
<a href="<?php echo $articleURL;?>" class="button-common-red">View Tour</a>
</article>
<div class="main-slider-sidebar">
<p><?php echo $noofdetailshort;?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php $i++;} ?>
```

i want to put this array data with for each loop means its a slider with different price heading and, i want to add statically those paras, but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Are you asking about this part, `$noofdetailshort = $para[0][0];`? You want that to access $para[0][0] in the first loop iteration, $para[1][0] in the second, and so on …? Well then simply increase a counter variable in your foreach loop, and use that to access the first array dimension.

Comment: yes but where should i do that, thats what i means. can you please code in comment, and this will repeat when the last one is complete the slide.

Comment: and i want that to access $para[0][0] in the first loop iteration, $para[1][0] in the second, then repeat those this array.

Comment: So you mean when you output the third record, you want it to access $para[0][0] again, etc.? Then you need to reset the counter variable when it exceeds the element count, or use the modulo operator. _“can you please code in comment”_ - please make an attempt yourself, show us what you tried, and report back with the results.

Comment: ok no problem i am sending you in comment.

Comment: hi edit the code, its working and thank you.